# When editing a post/product, how do I get it to remember the category (i/o me having to re-select it)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, edit, categories, dropdown

When I create a new listing (a new product posting) in my rails 5 app, I select a category via dropdown menu, eg electronics, home improvement, etc. If after creating an item I go back and edit it, I have to once again select a category or else it will no longer have a category. How do I tell the category to either be remembered or be pre-populated when I go to edit? Probably easy for a non-noob... thanks!

This is the category input field on the form:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :category %>
<%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id]}), :prompt => "Select one!") %>
```

I don't know what else I should post, so here's the categories controller code:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
@categories = Category.all
end

def show
end

def new
@category = Category.new
end

def edit
end

def create
@category = Category.new(category_params)

respond_to do |format|
if @category.save
format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was     successfully created.' }       
else
    format.html { render :new }
  end
end
end

def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @category.update(category_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
  end
end
end

def destroy
@category.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to categories_url, notice: 'Category was successfully destroyed.' }
end
end

private
@category = Category.find(params[:id])
end

def category_params
  params.require(:category).permit(:name, :desc)
end
end
```

Products table in DB:

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.text     "brief"
t.text     "description"
t.string   "buylink"
t.string   "verdict"
t.string   "category_id"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
t.string   "image"
t.string   "youtube"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.string   "goodverdict"
```

end

Answer (score 0):

To be honest. You can just use the usual scaffold controller actions. All you need to make sure is that your product item has a DB column for `category_id` and have the equivalent associations in your models, e.g.

```
product.rb 
  has_one :category
category.rb
  belongs_to :product
```

Than in your products_controller.rb add `category_id` to the `params` and when it is successfully saved it will be displayed in your edit as well as in your show views. For more detailed info check the DOCS on R-O-R associations. If your product should have more than one category you can choose a different type of association. Here the link:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I have, in category.rb: `has_many :products`

and in product.rb, I have `belongs_to :category`

Are you saying I need to change those to what you're recommending or should those have been fine?

Comment: totally fine, do you also have an id in the DB? e,g. category_id in products table?

Comment: Yes (I pasted the products table in the original question)

Comment: Ok. And you want to edit the category on the product?

Comment: Do you get the category for the product in the show view? Is it saved correctly?

Comment: Yes, it works correctly. Every item I create has a category properly associated with it. But if I edit an item and leave the category dropdown alone (as in, if I dont select a category), the product updates and saves with no category. I have to re-select the category or it goes away.

Comment: and if you change this part? |c| [ c.name, c.id] to |c| [ c.id, c.name]? Do you save id or name? Because usually it should be found by rails. May be it will work if you do the Categories.all to @categories, value should be 'id' and label should be 'name'. In doubt you need to specify categories in controller to Category.all. If it is saved with correct id it should display...